# mysql add http:// to all records in website column

Tags: mysql

I'm almost done transferring/reconstructing a substantial mysql db for new application. Column 'website' shows 'www.example.com'. Because the new application reads it as a hyperlink, I need the column to read 'http://www.example.com'. Is there a way to add the 'http://' in the beginning of each record for that column? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function%5Fconcat) function to do that:

```
UPDATE tbl SET website=CONCAT('http://', website);
```

If you want to get cleverer and only update columns which don't already have `http://` prepended, try

```
UPDATE tbl SET website=CONCAT('http://', website)
WHERE website NOT LIKE 'http://%';
```

**Update**

To prevent update to columns that have no site in them currently use this

```
UPDATE tbl SET website=CONCAT('http://', website)
WHERE website NOT LIKE 'http://%' AND website<>'';
```

Comment: Great, thanks!
Except... Now I have http://.. nothing in rows that didn't have a URL LOL

Comment: Ahh. Sorry didn't think off that... use `UPDATE tbl SET website='' WHERE website = 'http://'` to fix that `:)`

Comment: Hm. That took all the http://'s out again :) Couldn't I use something like
UPDATE tbl SET website=CONCAT('http://', website)
WHERE website NOT LIKE ' '; (as in empty)?

Comment: Not allowed yet... I'm just a minion :P

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat` to generate the new column:

```
UPDATE table1 SET website = CONCAT("http://", website);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concat command. Something like

```
SELECT CONCAT('http://', website) FROM table
```